# Elements with percentage width

Tags: css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdsBZ/6/)

Problems:

1. In my fiddle, you can see the last box(having date and buttons) is not the same size with others. This box should be divided into two having 50% width each.
2. On the left, I want the date container to be 50% relative to its parent box
3. On the right, I want the buttons container to be 50% relative to its parent box
4. The buttons should be aligned center relative to its container.

HTML

```
  <div class='gc_container'>
      <div class='gc_gift'>
          <div class='gc_gift_inner'>
              <div class='gc_amount'>TEST AMOUNT</div>
              <div class='gc_subtitle'>TESTING SUBTITLE</div>
              <div class='gc_hr'></div>
              <div class='gc_terms'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</div>
              <div class='gc_footer'>
                  <div class='gc_footer_expiry'>Exp. March 27, 2013</div>
                  <div class='gc_footer_use_nix'>
                      <div class='gc_footer_use'>
                          <div class='gc_footer_button_wrapper'>
                              <div class='gc_footer_use_txt'>Use</div>
                              <div class='gc_footer_use_icon'>icon1</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class='gc_footer_nix'>
                          <div class='gc_footer_button_wrapper'>
                              <div class='gc_footer_nix_txt'>Nix</div>
                              <div class='gc_footer_nix_icon'>icon2</div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.gc_gift {
    margin-top:1.5%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:1.5%;
    height: auto;
    width: 97%;
    position:relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border:1px solid #D1D1D1;
}
.gc_gift_inner {
    font-size:12px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border:0px solid #D1D1D1;
    display:table;
    margin-top:2.5%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:2.5%;
    height: auto;
    width: 95%;
    position:relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.gc_amount {
    color: red;
    font-size:2em;
}
.gc_subtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #707070;
}
.gc_hr {
    width: 95%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border-color: #D1D1D1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}
.gc_terms {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #707070;
}
.gc_footer {
    width: 95%;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
.gc_footer_expiry {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 40%;
    color: #707070;
    border: 0px solid yellow;
}
.gc_footer_use_nix {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60%;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    margin: auto;
}
.gc_footer_use {
    //display: table-cell;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #3F6EB6;
    border-radius: 1px;
    //padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    padding: 10%;
    position: relative;
    border:0px solid red;
}
.gc_footer_use_txt {
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.gc_footer_use_icon {
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.gc_footer_nix {
    //display: table-cell;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #D61920;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0x solid green;
    //padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    padding: 10%;
}
.gc_footer_nix_txt {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid blue;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.gc_footer_nix_icon {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid yellow;
    width: 50%;
}
.gc_footer_button_wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid blue;
}
.gc_container {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    display:table;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #D1D1D1;
    }
.gc_amount, .gc_subtitle, .gc_terms, .gc_footer {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: in .gc_footer_expiry in your CSS, the width is set to 40%, not 50%. Changing this, does it produce the outcome you were expecting?

Comment: @wribit Yes. I want the container of date and buttons to be fluid as well the buttons.

Comment: does that mean that changing the value to 50% worked, or...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For elements that should appear in the same way, I would never mix display, paddings and width. You're bound to get into trouble at some point...
If you do need to use table display, just set everything to have 'table' display, with the same padding and width, like so:

```
.gc_amount, .gc_subtitle, .gc_terms, .gc_footer {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:table;
    width:96%;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TdsBZ/11/

But like I said, I wouldn't mix those and would never use a set width together with padding. Margins are your friend; I would use those .gc_amount, .gc_subtitle, .gc_terms, .gc_footer elements just for the border and width, and have a second element within those tags to provide additional styling

here's another fiddle, with extra tags en different styling: http://jsfiddle.net/TdsBZ/14/

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with the other 3 problems also?

Comment: I think I figured out now the remaining 3 problems. Thanks for the help. Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TdsBZ/12/

Comment: excellent, I've created a second fiddle, slightly different in setup, if you're interested...